# sudo apt-get update issue error 502 bad gateway

Tags: server

I am getting below errors after hitting apt-get update on ubuntu server 14.04

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/source/Sources  502  Bad Gateway [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/source/Sources  502  Bad Gateway [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

uname -a
Linux ubuntuhost 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What does your /etc/apt/sources.list look like? Does it have this line in it anywhere? http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/source/Sources

Comment: Hi Genokan, Its throws 502 error for all lines.

W: Failed to fetch http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  502  Bad Gateway [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change the server select a server more near you from software and updates select other servers option. and then try again.[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried your suggestions but it is not succeed. Still i am facing same issue. I have changed download server too. What would be the exact issue.
Do you want any other information.
Anyway Thanks for your suggestions!!